# Plotting Points on a Map in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dictionary, plot

I want to plot different locations on a map of NY state. My current code plots the entirety of North America because I couldn't find how to plot just one state. I'm trying to set the latitude and longitude limits to the state of NY, but it's still giving me the entire country.

In addition, when I do `hold all` (or `hold on`) and try to plot the points, I get another figure that pops up with the title I specified, but just a blank, white square.

Another related question is that once I get the points plotted, I have to know what points they are. If I have the names in a separate cell array, how can I have MATLAB label the points based on which coordinates (which are stored in a separate column) correspond with which name (if the names are stored in yet another column)?

```
%% Plot map
latlim = [39 47];
lonlim = [-81 -70];

ax = worldmap('USA');
load coast
geoshow(ax, lat, long,...
'DisplayType', 'polygon', 'FaceColor', [.45 .60 .30])
states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true, 'BoundingBox', [lonlim' latlim']);
axesm('lambert', 'MapLatLimit', latlim, 'MapLonLimit', lonlim);
faceColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',...
    {'INDEX', [1 numel(states)], 'FaceColor', ...
    polcmap(numel(states))}); % NOTE - colors are random
geoshow(ax, states, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', ...
  'SymbolSpec', faceColors);
figure('Color', 'white')

title('PM2.5 Site in New York State in 2012');

hold all

% Plot points
axesm('lambert', 'MapLatLimit', latlim', 'MapLonLimit', lonlim');
datalat = str2double(datalat);
datalon = str2double(datalon);
scatterm(datalat, datalon)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a USA state map with `usamap('New York')` and plot an overlay text with `textm`. Here, 25 random points and their label are plotted on the figure.

The following plot

[image]

is produced by

```
latlim = [39 47];
lonlim = [-81 -70];

figure('Color','w');
usamap('New York')
shi = shaperead('usastatehi', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
            'Selector',{@(name) strcmpi(name,'New York'), 'Name'});
geoshow(shi, 'FaceColor', [0.3 1.0, 0.675])
textm(shi.LabelLat, shi.LabelLon, shi.Name, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')

nb_point = 25;
LAT = latlim(1) + (latlim(2)-latlim(1)).*rand(nb_point,1);
LON = lonlim(1) + (lonlim(2)-lonlim(1)).*rand(nb_point,1);
h = geoshow(LAT, LON, 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker', '+', 'Color', 'red');
textm(LAT, LON+0.3, num2str((1:nb_point)'), 'FontSize',14)
```

Comment: Can you explain the part in which you label the points? I have the names in a cell array.

Comment: As the doc says: _string may be a cell array of strings with the same number of elements as lat and lon. (For backward compatibility, string may also be a 2-D character array such that size(string,1) matches numel(lat))_. If you run `num2str((1:nb_point)'` in the command window, you will see the structure of the text. As simple as that!