# How to display 'imagesc' on top of 'worldmap' in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, coordinates, matlab-figure

x and y are vectors of coordinates - latitude and longitude. M is a matrix in which there is a value to each coordinate. I want that `imagesc` output will be displayed onto `worldmap` figure. The thing is that I'm not sure how to do that, for `imagesc` does not identify its axes as coordinates.

It is different from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283464/plotting-points-on-a-map-in-matlab), because I want to display image and not points.

```
 x=[ 28.3473   28.3584   28.3695   28.3807   28.3918   28.4029 ...]
y=[ -44.7629  -44.7527  -44.7425  -44.7322  -44.7220  -44.7117 ...]


figure
worldmap([min(y)-2 min(x)+2],[min(y)-2 max(y)+2])
load coastlines
plotm(coastlat,coastlon)


imagesc(x, y, M)
```

This is an example from `M` matrix (200x200). It contains weight of each cell in a grid. It's an output of a `griddata` interpolation function.:

```
NaN                    NaN                    NaN
38.7833096862656       NaN                    NaN
23.3637431502031    55.5086387622325    105.215090860562
15.0575548356974    33.2628405320320    84.5790859739102
6.96794335045748    12.7895951273141    59.3208680706436
0                        0              34.9244470279273
```

Comment: Does `hold on` work?

Comment: @m7913d It doesn't , I tried that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting Points on a Map in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283464/plotting-points-on-a-map-in-matlab)

Comment: Ihink that you shoul use geoshow, as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283464/plotting-points-on-a-map-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates on worldmap are not lon/lat. To project an image onto worldmap you should create reference matrix or vector and use [geoshow](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/examples/creating-maps-using-geoshow.html). Reference vector is in form [cells(pixels)/degree northern_latitude_limit western_longitude_limit]. You can use [vec2mtx](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/vec2mtx.html) to convert lat-lon to regular data grid, construct referencing object with i.e. [georefcells](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/georefcells.html), or even try matching the image to map manually ([1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/examples/creating-map-displays-with-data-in-projected-coordinate-reference-system.html),[2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/define-world-coordinates-using-spatial-referencing.html),[3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/define-world-coordinates-using-xdata-and-ydata-properties.html) approaches, all been rather laborious)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I get what you mean. How can it be done manually? I thought there must be an easy way.

Comment: Could you please share your image M?