# Plot points on map in matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping

I tried to plot points on a map in matlab using [Plotting Points on a Map in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283464/plotting-points-on-a-map-in-matlab) but for some reason the point won't appear. 
This is my code.

```
figure('visible','on');

    %%% Set the map boundaries
hi_lat=43.86;
lo_lat=41.23;
hi_lon= 6.08;
lo_lon=2.21;

    %%% Plot
worldmap ([lo_lat hi_lat], [lo_lon hi_lon]) % lat and lon bounds of your plot
geoshow('landareas.shp','FaceColor', 'green', 'EdgeColor', [0 0 0])
geoshow('worldcities.shp', 'Marker', '.',...
                       'Color', 'red')
labelLat = 43.5;
labelLon = 5.35;
textm(labelLat, labelLon, 'Marseille')
framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
lat=3.13;
lon=42.48;
geoshow(lat,lon, 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker', '+', 'Color', 'red'); %Part of the code that's not doing what I want it to do.

hold on
```

This gets me the following figure:
[image]

How do I plot this other point? Why will it not appear?

Comment: You might want to switch latitude and longitude values. Comparing to the values for Marseille, it seems you are drawing a point way on the other side of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Points you marked on the map do not appear because you have exceeded latitude and longitude limits. Try this;

```
lat=42.48;
lon=3.13;
```

Working now!
Here is the result:
[image: points.jpg]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but isn't that exactly what 's in my code? What do you want me to change?

Comment: hi_lat=43.86;
lo_lat=41.23;
hi_lon= 6.08;
lo_lon=2.21;

These are your boundaries. You have to change your boundaries or your longitude and latitude definition before your last geoshow().

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is here:

```
lat=3.13;
lon=42.48;
```

You just mixed up lat and lon, so its trying to plot some far away point off the map.

Try:

```
lat=42.48;
lon=3.13;
```